# I'm confused with Tomcat Worker (mod_jk)

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm currently studying connection between Apache Http Server and Tomcat.
I'm confused with the 'worker' concept.

[The official document](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/workers.html) says "**A Tomcat worker** is a Tomcat instance that is waiting to execute servlets on behalf of some web server. For example, we can have a web server such as the Apache HTTP Server forwarding servlet requests to a Tomcat process (**the worker**) running behind it."

My questions are:

1. That sentence means the former worker is a worker sending reqeust from web server to the latter worker(tomcat process like executing `.war`) ?
2. The former worker is a tomcat instance initiated by mod_jk ?

Comment: The reason you do not get answers (IMHO) is that your questions are unclear.  "former worker", "latter worker" ?  When apache receives a request, and determines that it should be handled by Tomcat, it sends the request to Tomcat, via mod_jk.  Tomcat does its magic and sends back the result.  So yes you have a worker in Apache talking to a worker in Tomcat.  mod_jk does not instantiate anything, it is just a "communication interface" used by Apache to talk to Tomcat.  Tomcat will instantiate new workers as load increases, based on it's own performance configuration.  Same with Apache.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thank you for your comment! The reason that why I thought mod_jk initiates something is [the official document](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/workers.html) says **"When starting up, the web server plugin will instantiate the workers whose name appears in the worker.list property"**

I think the worker in apache you mentioned is a tomcat instance (A Tomcat worker is a Tomcat instance ...). Then, what is a difference between tomcat instance and tomcat process ??

Comment: Apache https and Tomcat work a bit similar.  Each request in Apache httpd requires one worker to process it.  Then if the Apache httpd worker sees that the request must go to Tomcat, it will communicate with a Tomcat worker.  These are two separate software (they can be on different machines).  Then for process vs instance, it depends.  I do not remember if tomcat uses different processes for each worker, or just another thread (lightweight process in somes OS) for instances.  I know httpd can do both,depending on your MPM configuration.  I havent' work at that level of tomcat for a while.

Comment: @Nic3500 Then, **the Apache httpd worker** you mentioned is equal to **a tomcat worker** in official document ? Since, from my view, the both have same role for sending request to Tomcat process which executes like `.war`. Or, are they separate worker ?, sending servlet request like `httpd worker -> tomcat worker -> tomcat process`

Comment: Apache httpd is one server software.  Tomcat is another software.  It goes `browser <-> httpd worker <-> tomcat worker`.  httpd and tomcat are separated entities, separate processes.  httpd handles its own capacity (number of workers, processes, threads), and Tomcat does the same.  They both try to answer as many requests as they receive, based on performance configuration for each software.  So they are separate workers.  In large configurations, httpd and tomcat are on separate servers, for performance and security constraints.